# Grep Exclude Multiple dirs CSV not working

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, exclude

I'm trying to `grep` for the word `world`, while excluding any directories that are `mail`, `tmp`, or `.cpanel`. I can ignore them individually using the `--exclude-dir=name`, but from reading other threads it appears I should be able to use a comma separated list. However, I've had no luck trying:

```
grep 'world' --exclude-dir={./mail,./.cpanel,./tmp} -ri .
```

and

```
grep 'world' --exclude-dir={mail,.cpanel,tmp} -ri .
```

as neither work. Using `--exclude-dir` with only one directory works, as in:

```
grep 'world' --exclude-dir=mail -ri .
```

but I get back `tmp` can `.cpanel` listings.

How can I specify all dirs in one command (once I get the `.cpanel` and `tmp` excluded I suspect there may be a few more irrelevant dirs so I don't want to have a `--exclude-dir` per dir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `exclude-dir` is `grep` version dependent

The flag was introduced was introduced with > [2.5.2](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=29b030df):

> ```
> +Version 2.5.2
> +  - The new option --exclude-dir allows to specify a directory pattern 
> +    that will be exclided (sic) from recursive grep.
> ```

<sup>*( H/T to [Johnsyweb's answer on SO for tracking down the version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692318))*</sup>

Where implemented, it works as a regular, comma-separated list of directories to exclude, no spaces:

```
$ grep 'foo' -ri .                                                      
./a/test.txt:foo bar baz
./c/test.txt:foo bar baz
./b/test.txt:foo bar baz

$ grep 'foo' --exclude-dir={a,b} -ri .                                                      
./c/test.txt:foo bar baz
```

### Alternative, if your version of `grep` doesn't support `{}` and you don't want to keep typing out directories

Put the directories in an array, and expand that into the command:

```
$ exclude=( "mail" ".cpanel" "tmp" )
$ for dir in ${exclude[@]}; do echo "--exclude-dir=$dir"; done

--exclude-dir=mail
--exclude-dir=.cpanel
--exclude-dir=tmp
```

Use as below:

```
$ grep 'world' $(for dir in ${exclude[@]}; do echo "--exclude-dir=$dir"; done) -ri .
```

**Explanation**: the substitution `$()` will put your `--exclude-dir`s as arguments to grep `grep`.

Comment: I erred in my testing somehow. My original `grep` is working now. Sorry. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I donno, Even if you messed up, this is a plausible answer for other folks and is pretty well written. Feels like a bit of a waste to delete this and @TOOGAM's answer. I suggest picking the best one as the right answer, and voting appropriately over deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback- it may help those in future for whom it actually *doesn't* work (because they're on *BSD, or running ancient versions). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The following may or may not be a correct answer, depending on your definition of command:

`grep -iR 'world' . | grep -v mail | grep -v ".cpanel" | grep -v tmp`

(Actually, I'm pretty sure that ".cpanel" doesn't require quotes.  But I tend to play things safe, so rather than trying to remember all the nuances, if there's any punctuation then I tend to quote it.)

If your definition of "command" is when an executable is specified, then that is four commands and doesn't answer the question.  However, if your definition of "command" is based on when you press "enter", or if you say there are 5 commands that (one command that contains 4 other commands), then I have successfully provided a single command that does what you asked.  (Furthermore, instead of relying on a GNU extension called --exclude-dir, this approach works on more operating systems.)

Comment: `grep -v mail` will exclude any `mail` context, though, right? I only want to limit it when it is a directory.

Comment: Ah, you want grep to search all directories except those limited.  Hmm, bertieb's answer may be better for that.  Just to show roughly how this would be done using the approach I mentioned, maybe: `grep -ri "world" $( find . -type d -maxdepth 0 | grep -Ev ^[.]$ | grep -v mail | grep -v .cpanel | grep -v tmp | xargs)` # The "grep -Ev ^[.]$" removes the line containing just a period, so that this checks subdirectories